# Notification to user when particular word appear on webpage using python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I want notification when particular word is appear on website. for example, on news website if any news updated which contain word "GST", then it should notify me and provide me the detail of that news to be stored in any file.

And I want to monitor it continuously for change.

Is it possible with python using selenium, beautifulSoup, or lxml?

Using below provided code I'm able to get notify if any change is there. But I want notification for particular word appear and all the details regarding this.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib
import time

def fetch_html():
    # fetch logic
    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    resp = opener.open('www.example.com')
    data = resp.read()
    return data

def write_html(html):
    # write logic
    file = open("htmlString.txt", "w")
    file.write(html)
    file.close()
    # monitor(html)

def read_html():
    with open('htmlString.txt','r') as f:
        return f.read()

def monitor():
    write_html(fetch_html())
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        new_html = fetch_html()
        if new_html == read_html():
            print('Nothing has changed')
        else:
            print new_html
            print('Something has changed')
            write_html(new_html)

monitor()
```

Thank You.

**EDIT**
For example,
if source code contains

```
<p>The notification stipulates that manufacturers who have opted for composition scheme will now have to pay 1 percent Goods and Services Tax (GST) as against 2 percent earlier.</p>
<h1>GST council said that the e-way Bill system will have to be made ready by January 16 for trial runs.</h1>
```

Which tag contain word "GST" is not fixed. what I want is to search for element which has that word and the value contained within tags.

for example,

1. The notification stipulates that manufacturers who have opted for composition scheme will now have to pay 1 percent Goods and Services Tax (GST) as against 2 percent earlier
2. GST council said that the e-way Bill system will have to be made ready by January 16 for trial runs.

Thank you

Comment: You can use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) for that.

Comment: You can be notified if the content has GST using regrex. But,  you also need the details of that particular news. What exactly do you mean by details? location of the word in the page? or link to that news?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

with selenium first, you can find the elements that you want to check with `find_elements_by_xpath` method and get the text out of it with `.text` and iterate through that text.

## right click on element and inspect than on inspection find XPath

```
xpath_for_element=your path
element_to_check_for_keyword = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath_for_element)
text_to_check_for_keyword=element_to_check_for_keyword.text
```

then you can iterate through text_to_check_for_keyword to check if that keyword exists and you can create a while loop with time.sleep to set checking time for your own code above.

**edit:**

first of all, think of XPath as the path of that HTML element,
so every element under the same category has similar paths.

for example, India times have many sections on their webpage right?

but you can iterate through all sections XPath **by using ***

for example in the middle there is a **TOP News** section with a list. xpath of  the let say 6th element is

```
//*[@id="pageContent"]/div[1]/div/div[6]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[6]/a
```

so in order to reach every element in that section you use

```
//*[@id="pageContent"]/div[1]/div/div[6]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[*]/a
```

that `*` gives you all elements of that area. after that, you do that for every section like Comments, Market news, and others and iterate.

Comment: Yes, that can be a way but it is useful when I know the xpath. It is not useful in my case where xpath is not fixed.

Comment: can you give me an example of your xpath

Comment: That is what I am saying. Xpath is not fixed. News regarding GST can be contained in any tag.

Comment: consider indiatimes website : https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/ . What I want is if any tag/xpath has value GST in entire website, I want its entire content. The xpath of that content is not fixed.  Can it be located dynamically?

Comment: Thank You so much for your help BlanketSniffer. It helps me.